# Secure Web API Post Method with Username and Password

Tags: asp.net-web-api, restful-authentication

I have a Web API service hosted in Microsoft Azure. I need a certain POST method to be only accessible with one unique username and password.

I understand the [Authorize] method does a token based authentication but its not tied to a single username and password. In my app, the web api also does the login authentication, so anyone who registers can access this post method if im not mistaken. (Please correct me if im wrong)

I am new to this could you guide me the right way please.

This is my WebAPI Post method i want to secure access to with specific unique username&pass:

```
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpPost, Route("send")]
    public async Task<NotificationOutcome> Post([FromBody]string message)
    {

        string hubName = "myHub";
        string hubNameDefaultShared = "myHubNameDefaultShared";

        NotificationHubClient hub = NotificationHubClient
                        .CreateClientFromConnectionString(hubNameDefaultShared, hubName, enableTestSend: true);

        string installationId = string.Empty;

        var templateParams = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            ["messageParam"] = message
        };

        NotificationOutcome result = null;
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(installationId))
        {
            result = await hub.SendTemplateNotificationAsync(templateParams).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
        else
        {
            result = await hub.SendTemplateNotificationAsync(templateParams, "$InstallationId:{" + installationId + "}").ConfigureAwait(false);
        }

        return result;
    }
```

And this is how I currently access the POST Method:

```
var client = new RestClient("myWebApiRouteName");
            var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
            request.AddHeader("Postman-Token", "46c23eba-8ca6-4ede-b4fe-161473dc063a");
            request.AddHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
            request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
            request.AddParameter("undefined", messageBody, ParameterType.RequestBody);

            try
            {
                IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
                Console.WriteLine(response.Content);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
```

Comment: The *easiest* way to do it, if you want to hard code a user name with optional password would be to use http**s** and pass in the string as a part of the http message body or URI and then just do a comparison in code. Because you are using https the communication is encrypted end to end so no chance of someone getting the authentication credentials by packet sniffing or man in the middle. Of course this is not a very flexible approach and there are issues like someone reading the code or config file to glean the credentials.

Comment: @Igor thanks for your suggestion. I basically want to make sure only one person can access this POST method.  I was thinking username and password but can you suggest a better way to limit access to this post method?

Comment: Anything else would require you to store authentication credentials *or* implement a token based security. Those are more work but more flexible in the long run.